# creating spring boot gradle mutli project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am new to gradle.I am trying to create spring boot gradle mutli project in STS,but I didn't understand how to create.I am able to create single project.
So help me how to create multi project.

Root proect:nn-backend

build.gradle:

```
  plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
    }

    group = 'com.nn'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }



    allprojects {

        group = 'com.nn'
        //version = rootProject.version
        //sourceCompatibility = 1.8

        apply plugin: 'application'
        apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'jacoco'
        apply plugin: 'maven'
        apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

        mainClassName = 'com.cc.CcAdminApplication'

        version = rootProject.version



        ext {
            set('springCloudVersion', 'Greenwich.RC2')
        }

        configurations {
            provided
            compile.extendsFrom provided
            compile.exclude module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'
        }

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
            maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }

        }

        dependencies {

            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
            testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
            compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging')
            compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6')
            provided group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.20'
            compile group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', name: 'android-json', version: '0.0.20131108.vaadin1'

        }
    }
```

settings.gradle:

```
 rootProject.name = 'nn-backend'

    include ':nn-model'
    include ':nn-admin'
    include ':nn-common'
    include ':nn-filters'
```

sub-project:nn-common
build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.nn'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

sub-project:nn-filters
build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.nn'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile project(':nn-common')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Error:
[image: Error While doing refresh gradle of nn-filters project]

Comment: First you need to see what dependencies will be shared by all, then you create on root project.

Comment: @JonathanJohx how to create root project

Comment: I posted the answer about what I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You should first define the build.gradle for the `root project` should have the following configuration:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    group = projectGroup
    version = projectVersion
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion

    dependencies {

        // Here add the dependencies shared for each subproject.
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        // Here the the dependecies shared for testing
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        }
    }    
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
javaVersion=1.8
projectGroup = com.example
projectName = project-name
projectVersion = 0.1-SNAPSHOT

springBootVersion = 2.0.0.RELEASE
springCloudVersion = Finchley.RELEASE
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'project-name'
include 'sub-project-1', 'sub-project-2', ..
```

And let's define settings for **sub-project-1**

**build.gradle**

```
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.sub-project-1.Application'
}
```

Basically this'd be the `settings/properties` for multi-project **gradle**. the last one build.gradle for `sub-project-1` was shared all dependencies which has inside `allproject` body.

Comment: I have done all these things but when i add a project as dependency to another project(project name :"nn-filters") getting error while doing refresh gradle ERROR:Project with path ':nn-common' could not be found with root project 'nn-filters'

Comment: Could you add more details what you have on the question? it is too hard to help you without know what you are talking about.

Comment: Okay sorry I forgot to comment you that you need a root folder which has those setting of grade and inside this folder or root project  you need to add the sub projects, seems that is your issue

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand what your are saying.